# Same interface multiple times in constructor

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have created interface IValidator and few classes which implement this interface as you can see in the picture. I have class UserAccountManager which manages user account - creates new account, changes profile details, changes password, etc... Problem is that I need to validate user input in some cases (change password, registration...) and I need multiple validators for it. I don't think that this design is good because of multiple validators in the constructor. **Is there any better approach?**

[image]

Comment: Finally I have used Facade pattern - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/facade_pattern.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validators are usually implemented as a single class, but with multiple rules that can be configured dynamically. PHP example:

```
 Validator::make($data, [
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
```

From your example, I can see that all three rules(email, name, password) are related to some kind of user input authentication. So you can use only one validator, with the responsibility to validate user login.

Answer (score 0):

You could encapsulate validators in a single object, or a collection ( list or array ), so the constructor receives a single parameter.

```
.............................
..+---------------------+
..|....<<class>>........|
..|....ValidatorGroup...|
..+---------------------+
..|..[+]..void.RegisterValidator..|
..|.......(IValidator..NewValidator)...|
..|..[+]..void.Validate(..)...|
..+---------------------+
.............................
..+--------------------------+
..|.........<<class>>........|
..|....UserAccountManager....|
..+--------------------------+
..|..[+]..UserAccountManager..<<constructor>>..|
..|.......(ValidatorGroup..NewGroup)...|
..+--------------------------+
..|..[+]..void..ChangePassword.(..)..|
..|..[+]..void..RegisterNewUser.(..)..|
..+--------------------------+
.................................
```

You can also avoid assigning the validators, in the constructor, and add them as a single property.